# How to use Azure application insights metrics separately for each web test in .Net

Tags: azure-application-insights

I want to use metrics from app insights separately for web test wise instead of average from all the web tests

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: It is ask regarding exporting metrics data into .Net Application

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with Analytics. For instance, with this query:

```
availabilityResults
| where timestamp > ago(1d)
| summarize avg(duration) by bin(timestamp, 10m), name
| render timechart
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @ZakiMa , is there any API to fetch all these results seperately for web tests..from https://dev.applicationinsights.io/apiexplorer/metrics we are  getting output as average of all web tests